# How to access multiple foreign key using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to fetch the files of a student with all the data.

My Tables ( I summarized the tables for what I needed. ):

```
    students
     - id
     - name 
    student_files
     - id
     - student_id
     - type_file_id
     - file_url
    type_files
     - id
     - name
```

Model:

```
    // ...
    class Student extends Authenticatable{
    // ...

     public function files()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StudentFiles');
     }

    // ...
```

Controller:

```
    // ...
    class Student extends Authenticatable{
     public function getFiles(Request $request)
     {
        $user = Student::Find($request->user()->id)->load('files');
     }
    // ...
```

I've tried something like that... does not work.

```
     public function files()
     {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StudentFiles')->hasOne('App\TypeFiles');
     }
```

The Result of request:

```
// ...

    "files": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "student_id": 1,
            "type_file_id": 1,
            "file_url": "example.jpg",
        }
    ]

// ...
```

The result that I want

```
 // ...


       "files": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "student_id": 1,
                "type_file_id": 1,
                "name": "Profile",
                "file_url": "example.jpg",
            }
        ]
      // ...
```

I've tried it in several ways, but I can not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `typeFile` relation to StudentFile:

```php
class StudentFiles extends Model {
  public function typeFile()
  {
     return $this->hasOne('App\TypeFile', 'type_file_id');
  }
}
```

And then access it with eager load:

```php
$user = Student::with('files', 'files.typeFile')->find($request->user()->id);
$typeFileName = $user->files->typeFile->name;
```